# How to get the shortened URL after it's redirected?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have the short URL http://x.co/priceless which redirects to my website.
Now I want to display the text **x.co/priceless** on my page so visitors can see which link they visited.

I used `print $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` but that doesn't seem to work.

Is this possible and how can I do this? I use Wordpress btw.

Comment: I don't belive you get a referrer on a redirect if you browsed to http://x.co/priceless directly.

Comment: if you have control over shortening of the url, you can add parameters in there.

Comment: Thanks! I created a custom link which redirects to example.com/shortlink/?link=priceless and now it works!